# dynamically created js script onClick function variables not binding at current value

Tags: javascript, function, variables, dynamically-generated

```
newButton.onclick = function() {
  launchForm(
    this, 
    incoming[(10 * (incoming.length / fields)) + z],
    incoming[(48 * (incoming.length / fields)) + z]);
};
```

So when I generate 4 of these buttons dynamically, each of the four buttons passes the information of the 1st button into function launchForm. I suspect it's because when the variable z completes it's for statement it goes back to 0. If thats the case than instead of + z being + 1 for button 1 and + z being + 2 for button 2 its turning into + z being + 0 for all buttons.

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Edit: added to respond to request for more info:

```
    var newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.className = 'pure-button pure-button-primary mikeButton';
    newButton.innerHTML='Launch Form';
    newDiv4.appendChild(newButton);
```

So I am quite new at all of this so I may have used the wrong term. My understanding items which are created after the page is loaded is considered dynamic. --- Though I am new, I am quite confident the issue lies in my originally stated issue. Through setting up alerts and testing, I can see that the first button works exactly as it should, and all appropriate arguments are passed perfectly. It's just that buttons 2, 3 and 4 also launch what button one launches. Incoming.length does not change, fields does not change. the only thing that is different from when the first instance of newButton is created to the second instance is z. --- when i set up alerts immediately following the creation of the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th buttons, they accurately display the arguments which should be passed. but after the function which creates them is completed, which is based on a for statement using z as the variable, they convert back to as if z is 0 and use button 1's arguments (since z is equal to 0 in button 1's arguement). I would just hardcode + 1, +2, +3 into the code instead of z, but the amount of buttons created is contingent on the query. Sometimes 1 button, sometimes 10. So that really isn't an option.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please reveal the 'dynamical' part of your code, maybe its simply closure related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the handlers reference the current value of z when clicked. To use the value of z at definition I suggest

1. create the onclick handler by calling Function as a constructor and evaluate the currrent value of z in the body string:

   ```
   newButton.onclick = new Function("launchForm(this, incoming[(10 * (incoming.length / fields)) + "+ z + "], incoming[(48 * (incoming.length / fields)) + " + z  + "]);");
   ```
2. Alternatively save the value of z on the button object when creating the onclick handler:

   ```
   newButton["data-z"] = z;
   newButton.onclick = function() {....};
   ```

but replace references to "z" with "this['data-z']" in the function body.

Comment: Traktor53, I tried method 1 and couldn't get it to work. Likely an error on my side and I will make sure to come back to this when im not already running behind and figure it all out so I can understand it better. However, 2) worked and im up and running because of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ES5 does not use block context, instead it operates on function contexts. This means that in a `for` loop you have to use the index variable instantly, otherwise if you (for example) reference it in a callback function you'll get the value of that variable as it is during the callbacks execution.

There are multiple ways to fix this problem, probably it's easiest to demonstrate it in code:

```js
"use strict";

// first off, using [].forEach.call has some cons so we should have 
// a way to convert a NodeList to an Array
var toArray = function(input) {
  var output = [];
  // check if we have an array-like object
  if (input && typeof input.length === 'undefined') { return; }
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    output.push(input[i]);
  }
  return output;
}

// we get lists that contain links to parse
var linkLists = document.getElementsByClassName('link-list');
// and one div to store buttons
var buttonDiv = document.getElementById('buttons');

// we convert the NodeLists to arrays to get the forEach function
toArray(linkLists).forEach(function(list) {

  // now we iterate over the list children
  toArray(list.children).forEach(function(link, index) {

    var clickHandler = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating anywhere
      alert("Hi! I'm a link named '" + link.textContent +
            "' and my forEach index is: " + index +
            " (" + typeof index + ")");
    }

    link.onclick = clickHandler;

    // now let's use the link list as a mock data source and generate buttons
    var newButton = document.createElement('button');
    newButton.textContent = link.textContent;
    newButton.onclick = clickHandler;
    buttonDiv.appendChild(newButton);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<ul class="link-list">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

More details on [why [].forEach.call is discouraged](http://toddmotto.com/ditch-the-array-foreach-call-nodelist-hack/).

Now to show what's the usual pitfall:

```js
"use strict";

// we get lists that contain links to parse
var linkLists = document.getElementsByClassName('link-list');
// and one div to store buttons
var buttonDiv = document.getElementById('buttons');

// let's switch the forEach calls to for loops
// variables added for naming sanity
for (var x = 0; x < linkLists.length; x++) {
  var children = linkLists[x].children;
  
  for (var y = 0; y < children.length; y++) {
    var link = children[y],
        index = y;
    
    // everything is fine up to this point
    // now as there's no block context that would keep the variable
    // values for the handler we'll get the last value it had
    var clickHandler = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigating anywhere
      alert("Hi! I'm (possibly) a link named '" + link.textContent +
            "' and my for index is: " + index +
            " (" + typeof index + ") \n\n :(");
    }

    link.onclick = clickHandler;
  }
  
}

// now, what few beginners remember is that when there's no block
// context then all of the variables used above are available outside

// let's reuse the buttons div to get all variable values here
buttons.innerHTML = "Variable values after parsing for loops:" +
                    "<br/>x = " + x +
                    "<br/>y = " + y +
                    "<br/>link.textContent = " + link.textContent + 
                    "<br/>index = " + index;

// so now when we click the link the callback function gets
// the variables from above and not from it's block context
// as it would in other programming languages
```

```html
<ul class="link-list">
  <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="buttons"></div>
```

Comment: um i can definitely try this. so i currently have: for (var z = 0; z < incoming.length / fields; z++).... what 'unit' would i use to compare against incoming.length / fields?

Comment: Redid the answer completely, hope it's more understandable now :).